# AWS DefaultCredentialProvider set by AWS_PROFILE env var not working for terraform remote state

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform-provider-aws, aws-credentials

I have a simple Terraform root that provisions some AWS resources. It was initially set up with default local state. I use an AWS Profile to specify the target environment:

```
$ export AWS_PROFILE="some-aws-profile"
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "REDACTED:REDACTED",
    "Account": "account_id",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::account:assumed-role/somerolename/someusername"
}
```

And I can run `terraform plan` or `terraform apply` - resources get created in the target account. `provider "aws"` is configured with a region parameter only, all other details / creds are controlled via the AWS_PROFILE env var.

Now I am looking to move state to remote, with an S3 backend.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket = "my-bucket-name"
    key    = "some/path/to/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "eu-west-1"
  }
}
```

When I run `terraform init` with this, an error is thrown: `Error: error configuring S3 Backend: no valid credential sources for S3 Backend found.` I have also tried adding `profile = "some-aws-profile"` into the s3 backend block, but the same still fails.

Does a terraform / backend block use a different credential provider chain? Any reason why this backend config is not able to use AWS_PROFILE implicitly from environment var, or even when `profile` is added?

I don't have any `.credentials` files that I use for auth - in my local environment, i am using `aws sso login` to automatically manage credentials via `/cache/` subdirs in ~/.aws/sso or ~/.aws/cli - is this the part that is not compatible with backend?

*edit* adding in a snippet from `~/.aws/config`

This is what my profile looks like:

```
[profile some-aws-profile]
sso_start_url = https://myhostname.awsapps.com/start/#/
sso_region = eu-west-1
sso_account_id = <actual_account_id>
sso_role_name = somerolename
region = eu-west-1
output = json
```

To set up auth, i use `aws sso login` once AWS_PROFILE is set, and I authorize the request for temporary credentials in whereever CLI stores them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was not working in 0.13.6 with the latest version of terraform provider aws (4.15.1).

Upgrading to TF 1.2.0 resolved this - SSO profile is used for credential loading in the S3 backend.